# Polymorphism in game

Tags: c++, performance, polymorphism

I'm making a game with C++ and I'm considering whether to use polymorphism or not.
I know in most of the time using polymorphism is better, but the problem is I made some particle effects in the game and there are hundreds of them popping up in a second. If I use polymorphism in this case, I'll be frequently allocating and releasing memory, which will definitely slows down the game.

So, should I use polymorphism even having to frequently New/Delete objects?

By the way, if my grammer is broken, please correct me. I'm still learning English.

Comment: Why do you say "If I use polymorphism ... I'll be frequently allocating and releasing memory". Polymorphism means you have a hierarchy of classes in which some virtuals get overridden. The amount of newing and deleting you have to do doesn't depend on how polymorphic your design is. So, first things first: are your particles all basically the same or do they come in a hierarchy of types? If the latter, are there any functions which all particles perform but in different ways?

Comment: It's common for particle effects to use some kind of object pool to reduce allocations. Also you don't have to use polymorphism for either everything or nothing.

Comment: I didn't express it clearly. I think my problem is actually about the performance about new/delete. It's not a problem normally but in game there are hundreds or thousands of them are created in a second. So if frequently new/delete matters a lot to performance, I'll rather use particle pool. If not, then I think I'll just use polymorphism.

Comment: I'm curious.  Can pointers be used?  Would they be faster?

Answer (score 1):

If you would not use polymorphism, you would still need the same amount of new/delete to create all your particles. Polymorphism will not degrade significantly your performance.  It only results in some indirect function call, instead of direct calls.  This is something which is supported by the instruction set of almost all modern CPUs.

So if polymorphism addresses well your game design, go for it.

Coming back to you initial issue of creating/deleting lots of similar objects like particles, you may consider use of the [flyweight](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/flyweight.html) design pattern, which "*uses sharing to support a large numbers of fine-grained objects efficiently*" (Design patterns, Gamma & al.)

Comment: The problem with polymorphism is data structures which can hold any of the derived types. You can no longer use `vector<T>` but must use pointers of some kind, which then raises the question of where they point to.

Comment: Yes, polymorphism requires pointers; Is this really a problem ?  On the other side if you use `vector<T>` to create AND delete particles you'll have overhead moving elements around. Another alternative is to use a vector of pointers to elements which are stored pools (to avoid allocation, one pool per object types).  But it's difficult to give specific advice without seing the code the OP is talking of.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simple fact of using polymorphism will have no or very little impact over performance itself, it all depends on how you design your game.

So my tips are:

1. Make some testing first, simulate some things you could do in the game and see how is the performance, is it acceptable? If so, don't optimize yet!
2. If performance is not bad, go for maintainability! Don't be afraid of using language resources at first place, write the code the way it will be easier to maintain the code afterwards, don't make [Premature Optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).
3. If you are having problems with performance, try to find the bottlenecks and fix it. If you think the problem is because the frequency of allocation and releasing of memory, try another approach, like making some kind of particle buffer, make the particles assume some invalid state and re-use them when you need again avoiding releasing and allocating memory too frequently.